# Why do we maximize according to the values of Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics, optimization

In some Lagrangian problems, when we use the lagrange multipliers to minimize a function $f(x)$ they write:
\begin{equation}
\max_{\lambda,\mu} \min_{x}\mathcal{L} =  \max_{\lambda,\mu}\min_{x} \Big( f(x) - \lambda h(x) - \mu g(x) \Big)
\end{equation}
where $\lambda, $ and $\mu$ are the lagrange multipliers of the two corresponding constraints.
My question is why we maximize $f(x)$ according to the values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$? Why isn't minimum also?

Comment: Who are they? Which page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we wish to satisfy both constraints $g(x)=0$ and $h(x)=0$ while minimizing $f(x)$, one strategy is to write $$ \mathcal{L} =  f(x) - \lambda h(x) - \mu g(x) $$ and commit to (1) determining $$\min_{x} \mathcal{L}$$ while (2) satisfying $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}=0\quad\mathrm{and}\quad \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mu}=0.$$ Exactly equivalent, right?

But of course, maximization or minimization of a certain function for changes in a certain variable would also imply that the first derivative with respect to that variable is zero. So we might instead try to solve $$\max_{\lambda,\mu}\min_{x} \mathcal{L}\ \ \mathrm{or}\ \ \max_{\mu}\min_{x,\lambda} \mathcal{L}\ \ \mathrm{or}\ \ \max_{\lambda}\min_{x,\mu} \mathcal{L}\ \ \mathrm{or}\ \  \min_{x,\lambda,\mu} \mathcal{L},$$ which would yield the same result as long as no inflection points exist. Presumably your source has shown this and has also shown that the first term is sufficient, i.e., that $\mathcal{L}$ is always concave downward with respect to $\lambda$ and $\mu$.